# How to yield to keypress detection in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

In my nodejs application, I am doing some cpu-intensive work in a tight loop:

```
while(!isQuit) {
    doMyWork();
}
```

For the sake of explanation, doMyWork() is a simple method that writes random data into a file.

At the start of the code, I have added logic to check for keyboard press:

```
var isQuit = false;
const readline = require('readline');
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
  if (key.name === 'q') {
    isQuit = true;
  }
});
```

The idea is to quit my processing when the user presses "q" on the keyboard.

The problem is that the keyboard presses are not being looked at. I think it is primarily because my tight loop is not giving a breather to the keyboard event processing.

Is there some function call I can make within my tight loop to yield for keyboard event processing?

Or, is there a way to rewrite my while loop such that doMyWork() keeps getting called asynchronously until the keypress event is received?

Comment: Javascript is single threaded.  You will need to break the loop into chunks to give the event loop a chance to respond to the keypress.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant to ask. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [an interval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args) rather than a loop.

```
let handle = setInterval(function(){
  if (isQuit) {
    clearInterval(handle);
  } else {
    doMyWork();
  }
}, 1);
```

That should give stdin a chance to break into the event loop.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: If doMyWork() blocks for a noticeable amount of time wont this suffer the same problem?  doMyWork() will have to be refactored to do portions of work during the intervals.

Comment: @PeterVC it's my understanding from the OP's post that `doMyWork()` is already an increment of processing. If it's not, then yes.